# Weibull distribution probabilities

Tags: probability-distributions

I am reading the following [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.03821.pdf) on page 15 it is written that for Weibull distribution  with scale and shape parameters estimated at 13.6 and 2.6, they estimate the following probabilities:
$$p_1=P(W<7)=0.18$$
$$p_2=P(7<W<14)=0.51$$
$$p_3=1-p_1-p_2=P(14<W<21)=0.31$$
I know that the Weibull distribution is given by: 
$$f(x)=\frac{k \left(\frac{x}{\lambda }\right)^{k-1} \exp \left(-\left(\frac{x}{\lambda }\right)^k\right)}{\lambda }$$
so for $k=2.6$ and $\lambda=13.6$ we should be able estimate $f(x)$ or the probability. I know that for fixed $x$ this is simple for example $f(10)=0.07$. I am trying to understand the notation $P(W<7)$, $P(7<W<14)$ and $P(14<W<21)$ how does one calculate the probabilities in that case?

Comment: The function $f$ is a **probability density function** (PDF), which you can think of as a kind of "continuous histogram" for the distribution. A histogram tells you, for any value the random variable takes on, the probability that it takes on that value. A PDF tells you a variation of that.  The probability that a random variable with a Weibull distribution takes on any given value is $0$, so what the PDF tells you is the probability per unit value. I.e., if you were to find the probability that the variable equals somewhere between $9.5$ and $10.5$, it would be very close to $f(10)$.

Comment: In order for you to find the probability that the random variable falls within a given *interval*, you need to integrate the PDF between the bounds of that interval.  Conveniently, the antiderivative of the PDF (calibrated so that it always falls between $0$ and $1$) is the **cumulative distribution function** (CDF), typically denoted $F(x)$.  Then, for example, $F(14) - F(7) = P(7 \leq X \leq 14)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probabilities are found by integrating the density function over the interval of interest. For example, $P(W<7) = \int_0^7 f(x)\, dx$ and $P(7<W<14) =\int_7^{14} f(x)\, dx$.

Note that the [Weibull CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) is $\int_0^x f(t)\, dt = 1 - e^{-(x/\lambda)^k}$ for $x\ge 0$, so we have $P(a < W < b) = F(b)-F(a)$ for all $0\le a \le b$, with $F(x)= 1 - e^{-(x/\lambda)^k}$.